# Which server should I put my message queue on: my worker server or my application server?

Tags: redis, message-queuing

I have two EC2 servers.  One is the application server (serving HTTP/S requests) and one is a "worker" server processing jobs.

I am wanting to move to use Huey (a task queue) which uses Redis as a backend.

I don't want to spin up another server just to run Redis, but I'm not sure what the best practice is - should I run Redis on my application server or my worker server, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have only two servers it doesn't really matter.

I'd usually put the queue on a separate set of servers or on the application servers if there are budget constraints. Since workers should be the most easy part to scale up and down it would be silly to take down the queue when reducing the number of workers.